# Can't set width and height to the backgroundn

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

Hi guys I can't set the width and height to backgrounds

I have an empty movieclip in the stage that holds a background

bg._width = Stage.width;

bg._height = Stage.height;

the background is loaded from XML and works fine since I'm not set the width and height

but if I set: bg._width = Stage.width and bg._height = Stage.height

Flash gives me white background??

Comment: so you're loading images into this empty "bg" movie clip and it's working fine. but if you try to set the width and height of the "bg" mc your background disappears?

Comment: How do you load an image from XML? Please post more of your code.

Comment: this.createEmptyMovieClip("bg", this.getNextHighestDepth());

bg._x = 0;

bg._y = 0;

bg.loadMovie(background[0]);

up here works very well,

bg._width = Stage.width;
bg._height = Stage.height;

when I try to set the width and height the background image is not in the stage, Flash gives me a white background..

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may be running into an issue because you're trying to use stage.width instead of stage.stageWidth.

Here's a blog post explaining the difference: http://blog.pekpongpaet.com/2008/08/13/flash-actionscript-stagestagewidth-vs-stagewidth/

If your only content is a movieclip that's empty, stage.width == 0. Try stage.stageWidth etc and you should be good! :)